# CMake Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: cmake

What does the Workflow look like if you're developing in Visual Studio but using CMake? I need to maintain CMakeLists.txt manually, but I'm building the project using the default VS solution file. How do I know I haven't made mistakes in my CMake file?

Comment: "How do I know I haven't made mistakes in my CMake file?" - Just try to configure your CMake project for Visual Studio and build resulted solution. If this causes no errors, then there is a high chance that your `CMakeLists.txt` is correct.

Comment: So I have to manually update the build after every change?

Comment: @Xoteric I recommend building the `ZERO_CHECK` target check any errors during configuration. This target is automatically built when you build any other target, but if there's any error in the cmake files the console output may vanish during realoading the solution. Btw: If you use Visual Studio Code the project should be reconfigured immediately when saving a cmake file; it also creates a VS solution...